# Window.crypto.signText alwasy return internalError

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a USB token. In the JavaScript code, running in Mozilla Firefox, I am using window.crypto.signText to sign some text. When the code executes the dialog box for selecting the token pops up, I select the right token, enter a PIN and then I get internal error. How can I fix? Where could the problem be? Do I have to set somehow the certificate I am using?

Comment: At least show us *what* "internal error" you get. And the relevant part of your code would be nice as well.

Comment: Hi, the code looks like this (JS): window.onload = function() {
 console.log('onload');
 var str=window.crypto.signText("hello","ask");
 alert(str);
}; And str="error:internalError"

Comment: Hi, the code looks like this (JS): **window.onload = function() { console.log('onload'); var str=window.crypto.signText("hello","ask"); alert(str); };** After execution *str="error:internalError"*

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't have the certificate chain of the issuer of your certificate set as trusted in firefox.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292238

> a call to crypto.signText returns "error:internalError" if the issuer
>   of your certificate "is not trusted", ie. none of the CAs in the
>   CA-chain has been set to  "This certificate can identify mail users".